# How to prevent hotlinking for subdirectories only?

Tags: apache-2.4, wildcard, directory, hotlinking

I want to prevent hotlinking to all subfolders in `/var/www/store` but at the same time allow linking to its index page. I tried doing this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/store">
  DirectoryIndex index.html
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/store/*">
  SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ^http://example.com/ accept
  Require env accept
</Directory>
```

But the index.html is forbidden when I tried accessing from a link outside. Next I tried appending a trailing slash.

```
<Directory "/var/www/store/*/">
```

It doesn't work too. Is this a bug in Apache? Ain't the `<Directory>` directive supposed to match directories only?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, `<Directories>` match anything in a directory or subdirectory.

I've not done this before, but this would seem correct behavior to me. Why not try fold the 2 Directory entries into 1 and add

> SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ".html" accept

Comment: Can you clarify the first point? Sorry, I don't quite get it. For the second point, yes, that's a good suggestion. I would try that.

Comment: I don't think you need Directory "/var/www/store/*" and "Directory "/var/www/store/" - you can simply have "Directory "/var/www/store/" and add the SetEnv and require env stuff in that virtualhost along with the DirectoryIndex parameter if that is needed.

Comment: To clarify again, I am asking why `index.html` is matched by `<Directory "/var/www/store/*">`, resulting in a Forbidden error, since it is supposed to be matching directories and subdirectories.

Comment: <Directory> matches "the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories." (See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) - ie Files are also matched.